# How to check whether a node belongs to html or the browser window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I'm working on a Firefox extension, in that I have a node which I want to know that whether the node belongs to the `html` (I mean the node belongs to `document.body` elements like `div`, `p`, etc) or just the `window` like `menu`, `toolbar`, etc.

Is there a way to do it in JavaScript?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, since I'm new to JavaScript. Let me know if there's something unclear or ambiguous.

I'm very thankful for your responses. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I know of is to follow the parent chain and see if you find document.documentElement or not.

In jQuery, you can use `jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, el)`

In YUI3, you can use `node.inDoc()`

Curiously, both the jQuery and YUI implementations don't just follow the parent chain - they check for the existence of the `.contains(el)` or `.compareDocumentPosition(el)` methods on the desired ancestor and use whichever of those is present.